# Replace contents of a column in powerQuery based on another column with M language

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to replace the values of a column depending on the values of a different column. I have a column named TIPO DE USUARIO and I want the values of this column to change if the values of a column named SERVICIO is Especial. In the applied steps section of power query, the last step is Renamed Columns.

I have the following code:

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns", each [SERVICIO], each if [SERVICIO] = "Especial" then [TIPO USUARIO] = "Especial" else [SERVICIO],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"TIPO DE USUARIO"})

However, nothing changes in the talble TIPO DE USUARIO even though the column SERVICIO has some values Especial.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GmHC.png)

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results as copiable text.

Answer (score 0):

try this in powerquery

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns", each [TIPO DE USUARIO], each if [SERVICIO]="Especial" then _ else [SERVICIO] , Replacer.ReplaceText, {"TIPO DE USUARIO"})
```

Unclear, but you can also change the ="Especial" to <>"Especial" to reverse the check

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your question is. My code seems to work fine for what you requested. Your comment is NOT the code I provided. Adding image to my answer.

Comment: nothing changes 

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercased Text2", each [TIPO DE USUARIO], each if [SERVICIO] = "ESPECIAL" then [TIPO DE USUARIO] = [SERVICIO] else null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"TIPO DE USUARIO"})

Comment: Again, your comment is not the code I provided. Your pasted image shows Especial, your comment code says ESPECIAL   They are not the same.  PowerQuery is case sensitive.  Sorry, I can't help you any more. You have not provided enough information to tell what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "sample data" I worked off of:

```
+---------------------+----------------+
|      SERVICIO       | TIPO DE USARIO |
+---------------------+----------------+
| Especial            |                |
| Especial            |                |
| Especial            |                |
| Odontologia         | Estudiante     |
| Laboratorio Clinico | Estudiante     |
| Especial            |                |
| Laboratorio Clinico | Estudiante     |
| Especial            |                |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

What you are looking for is a simple conditional column, then you delete the original "TIPO DE USARIO" column.

Here's the M code:

```
let

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SERVICIO", type text}, {"TIPO DE USARIO", type text}}),

    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TIPO DE USARIO 2", each if [SERVICIO] = "Especial" then "Especial" else [TIPO DE USARIO]),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Conditional Column",{"TIPO DE USARIO"}),

    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"TIPO DE USARIO 2", "TIPO DE USARIO"}})

in

    #"Renamed Columns"
```

This is the output:

```
+---------------------+----------------+
|      SERVICIO       | TIPO DE USARIO |
+---------------------+----------------+
| Especial            | Especial       |
| Especial            | Especial       |
| Especial            | Especial       |
| Odontologia         | Estudiante     |
| Laboratorio Clinico | Estudiante     |
| Especial            | Especial       |
| Laboratorio Clinico | Estudiante     |
| Especial            | Especial       |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: If one of us has answered your question, please mark that answer as such. Thank you.